# Contador Regressivo em HTML & JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Então pessoal, desejo fazer um contador regressivo que você informa a hora que você entrou no local, e ele faz a soma por 6hrs e 20 min, e diz pra você a hora que você vai sair e pega essa hora e subtrai pela hora atual do computador e joga pro contador fazer a contagem regressiva. No meu código atual tenho um relógio que puxa a hora atual do computador e um contador regressivo que você informa a hora e ele regride, então meus problemas são os seguintes:

1 - Meu contador não suporta horas, somente minutos e segundos.
2 - Não sei como fazer para somar a hora informada da hora definida de 06:20:00hrs e em seguida mostrar em algum lugar na página esta hora.
3 - Não sei como fazer a subtração da hora que a pessoa vai sair da hora atual do computador e jogar essa hora pro contador.

```html
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Contagem Regressiva</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<CENTER>
<FORM name="sw">
 <TABLE border="0" width="100%">
  <tr align="center">
   <td>
    <table border="3" width="30%">
     <tr align="center">
      <td>
       <SPAN ID="Clock"></SPAN>
       <br>
       <input type="text" name="beg2" size="7" value="00:05">
      </td>
      <td>
       <input type="button" value="Iniciar" onclick="Down()">
      </td>
     </tr>
     <tr align="center">
      <td colspan="2">
       <input type="text" name="disp2" size="20">
      </td>
     </tr>
    </table>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </TABLE>
</FORM>
</CENTER>

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">

 var Elem = document.getElementById("Clock");
 function Horario(){
  var Hoje = new Date();
  var Horas = Hoje.getHours();
  if(Horas < 10){
   Horas = "0"+Horas;
  }
  var Minutos = Hoje.getMinutes();
  if(Minutos < 10){
   Minutos = "0"+Minutos;
  }
  var Segundos = Hoje.getSeconds();
  if(Segundos < 10){
   Segundos = "0"+Segundos;
  }
  Elem.innerHTML = Horas+":"+Minutos+":"+Segundos;
 }
 window.setInterval("Horario()",1000);


 var down;
 var cmin2,csec2;
 function Minutes(data) {
  for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++)
  if(data.substring(i,i+1)==":")
  break;
  return(data.substring(0,i));
 }

 function Seconds(data) {
  for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++)
  if(data.substring(i,i+1)==":")
  break;
  return(data.substring(i+1,data.length));
 }

 function Display(min,sec) {
  var disp;

  if(min<=9){
   disp=" 0";
  }else{
   disp=" ";
  }

  disp+=min+":";

  if(sec<=9){
   disp+="0"+sec;
  }else{
   disp+=sec;
  }

  return(disp);
 }

 function Down() {
  cmin2=1*Minutes(document.sw.beg2.value);
  csec2=0+Seconds(document.sw.beg2.value);
  DownRepeat();
 }

 function DownRepeat() {
  csec2--;
  if(csec2==-1) {
   csec2=59;
   cmin2--;
  }

  document.sw.disp2.value=Display(cmin2,csec2);
  if((cmin2==0)&&(csec2==0)){
   alert("Acabou a Contagem!!!");
  }else{
   down=setTimeout("DownRepeat()",1000);
  }
 }
</SCRIPT>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Não ficou muito claro o que você quer fazer. Você quer um contador onde a pessoa coloca a hora que entrou e ele informa pro usuário a hora em que este vai sair, ao mesmo tempo que faz um countdown pra alertar o cara na hora que ele for sair que deu as 6 horas e 20? Ficou meio confuso

Comment: Exatamente como você explicou Máttheus Spoo, além de mostrar a hora(fixa) que a pessoa vai sair, ele faz uma contagem regressiva de quanto tempo falta.

Comment: Como assim o usuário vai informar a data que ele entrou? Ele pode errar na digitação. Não acha melhor o javascript pegar a hora que ele entrou?

Comment: Bem-vindo Ramon Martins,  caso alguma resposta de alguma pergunta sua resolva seu problema não deixe de marcá-la como aceita. Veja como em https://i.stack.imgur.com/jx7Ts.png e porque em https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079 Aproveite e faça um tour pelo sita https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 2):

Veja se resolve:

```js
    //para contagem regressiva minutos = 380 = 6 horas e 20 minutos
    var data = new Date(),
        minutos = 380;
    // acrescentando 380 minutos a data
    data.setMinutes(data.getMinutes() + minutos);  

    // apresenta no input id disp2 data e hora de saida  
    document.getElementById('disp2').value = "Até " + data.toLocaleString();
      
    function atualizaContador() {
      var hoje = new Date();
      var ss = parseInt((data-hoje) / 1000);

      var mm = parseInt(ss / 60);
      var hh = parseInt(mm / 60);
      var dd = parseInt(hh / 24);
       ss = ss - (mm * 60);
      mm = mm - (hh * 60);
      hh = hh - (dd * 24);
       var faltam = '';
      faltam += (dd && dd > 1) ? dd+' dias, ' : (dd==1 ? '1 dia, ' : '');
      faltam += (toString(hh).length) ? hh+' hr, ' : '';
      faltam += (toString(mm).length) ? mm+' min e ' : '';
      faltam += ss+' seg';
        if (dd+hh+mm+ss > 0)  {
             document.getElementById('contador').value = faltam;
             setTimeout(atualizaContador,1000);
        } else {
             document.getElementById('contador').value = 'Acabou a Contagem!!!';
             alert("Acabou a Contagem!!!");
        }
    }
    atualizaContador();

      //para o relogio
     var Elem = document.getElementById("Clock");
     function Horario(){
      var Hoje = new Date();
      var Horas = Hoje.getHours();
      if(Horas < 10){
       Horas = "0"+Horas;
      }
      var Minutos = Hoje.getMinutes();
      if(Minutos < 10){
       Minutos = "0"+Minutos;
      }
      var Segundos = Hoje.getSeconds();
      if(Segundos < 10){
       Segundos = "0"+Segundos;
      }
      Elem.innerHTML = Horas+":"+Minutos+":"+Segundos;
     }
     window.setInterval("Horario()",1000);
```

```html
    <FORM name="sw">
     <TABLE border="0" width="100%">
      <tr align="center">
       <td>
        <table border="3" width="30%">
         <tr align="center">
          <td>
           <SPAN ID="Clock"></SPAN>
           <br>
           <input type="text"id="contador" name="beg2" size="30" value="00:05" style="text-align:center;">
          </td>
         </tr>
         <tr align="center">
          <td>
           <input type="text" id="disp2" name="disp2" size="20" style="text-align:center;">
          </td>
         </tr>
        </table>
       </td>
      </tr>
     </TABLE>
    </FORM>
```